# can we use the SCSS css preprocessor in Angular 1.6.6 which is already using LESS as css preprocessor?

Tags: css, angularjs, sass, less

I want to use LESS as well as SCSS in Angular version 1. 
Do I need to compile SCSS and stylus files first to CSS and import that into my app? or is there any good alternative?

Background: I have two application, one with Angular 4 and one with Angular 1. Angular 4 is using scss and angular 1 is using LESS. 
I want to use angular 4 apps inside angular 1 keeping angular 1's look and feel?

Comment: what u use to build your project? webpack, gulp, ...?

Answer (score 1):

I don´t understand exactly what your problem :P

You can do your app with css1, css3, less, sass whatever you want, is not escencial to build an angular application.

If you are using sass and want less, you have to migrate it manualy (I think).

I recommend you, SASS.

:)

Comment: I have existing  APP which is developed in Angular. I have SAAS and want to use less.

Comment: You have to migrate manually, but if you have SASS why you don't want to use it?, SASS is modern than LESS and are similar...